# Integration of powers: nested $dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How do we solve the likes of the following expression:
$$
\int_0^2 \frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{1 + 2x^2}}\,dx 
$$

I'm bothered by the nested $dx$ in the numerator. How is this solved using the general power rule. Thank you very much!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I have tried to interpret your notation, please fix it if it's not like the original. I'm inclined to consider it a typo in the exercise, as the double $dx$ is meaningless.

Comment: it's the write interpretation

Comment: Some authors put the dx in the numerator of fractional expressions like this one. I personally never do that because I want to maintain the separation between height and width of the Riemann rectangles. But my guess is, someone just made  typo and put the dx in both places.

Comment: so this is grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above in the comments, this is most likely a typo. 
\begin{align}
\int^2_0\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+2x^2}}dx
&=\frac{1}{4}\int^2_0\frac{4x}{\sqrt{1+2x^2}}dx\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+2x^2}\right]^2_0\\
&=1\\
\end{align}